# Como hacer que una imagen se ajuste al contenedor usando Bootstrap 5

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap-5

Me gustaría saber cual es la forma adecuada para que una imagen tome el ancho y alto de un contenedor no quiero que sobren los espacios, estoy utilizando *Bootstrap 5* y con la clase `img-fluid` puedo hacer que la imagen crezca junto con su contenedor padre.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<main class="container d-flex align-content-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 bg-warning">
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis amet dolore provident praesentium vel, nam hic adipisci maxime maiores ab quidem ipsam sit facere mollitia pariatur accusantium quos voluptas voluptate?
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 bg-primary ">
            <img src="./images/image-header-desktop.jpg" alt="header" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Les coloque 2 fondos de distintos colores para diferenciar los contenedores, y me percato que en el contenedor que tiene la imagen no toma todo el ancho ni alto, quedan espacios de color azul y no deseo eso.

Comment: No estoy muy seguro, pero tal vez es porque la clase `col-*` añade un padding por defecto, por lo tanto su contenido no se ajustará totalmente sino que dejará este espacio de padding. Intenta agregar la clase `p-0` al contenedor `col` y verifica el resultado. Saludos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Por defecto hay un espaciado (padding horizontal) en los contenedores dentro de `row`, por lo que debes quitarlo usando una regla de padding como `px-0` (`padding-left` y `padding-right` 0px)

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="container d-flex align-content-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 bg-warning">
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis amet dolore provident praesentium vel, nam hic adipisci maxime maiores ab quidem ipsam sit facere mollitia pariatur accusantium quos voluptas voluptate?
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 bg-primary px-0">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/728x90.png" alt="header" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 3):

Por defecto todas las col tiene una propiedad de padding definida, para modificar esa espacio interno puedes usar las clases de [Spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/) que bootstrap5 tiene. en la liga puedes encontrar mas sobre el tema.

Con esa información puedes resolver tu problema agregando la clase `.p-0` para eliminar todos los espacios

```
<div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 bg-primary p-0">
                <img src="./images/image-header-desktop.jpg" alt="header" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
```